# Como pesquisar por número digitado?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma barra de pesquisa através de um teclado numérico, como faço para fazer pesquisa de página por número digitado

Código html:

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>

  <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!----- captura URL
            document.title = "Título de la pagina";
            var answer_mode = 0;
            function clear1() {
                document.forms["calculator"].display.value = "";
            }

            function clear() {
                clear1();
            }

            function number(ch) {
                if (answer_mode) {
                    clear1();
                    answer_mode = 0;
                }

                document.forms["calculator"].display.value += ch;
                var hoja=ch
            }

            
            function ver(){
                location.href="/"+document.calculator.display.value;
            }

            -->

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="calculator">
            <input name="display" value="" size="6" style="text: Arial; font-size: 20pt; background-color:#58D3F7" >
            <input type="button" value="ver" onclick="ver()" />
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  <input value=" 7 " onclick="number(7)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 8 " onclick="number(8)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 9 " onclick="number(9)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  <input value=" 4 " onclick="number(4)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 5 " onclick="number(5)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 6 " onclick="number(6)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  <input value=" 1 " onclick="number(1)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 2 " onclick="number(2)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td>  <input value=" 3 " onclick="number(3)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input value=" 0 " onclick="number(0)" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>  <input value="C" onclick="clear1()" type="button" style='width:50px; height:50px;font-size:30px;color:blue'></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não consegui entender nem o que você tem, nem o que quer fazer, nem o erro que acontece. Pode explicar melhor? O que é "barra de pesquisa através de um teclado numérico", e o que seria "fazer pesquisa de página por número digitado"?

Comment: Olá César, 

sou iniciante na área de desenvolvimento e criei um teclado numérico virtual, para utilizá-lo como uma barra de pesquisa dentro de um site, onde ao digitar um número e clicar no botão ver o usuário consiga ser direcionado para uma página dentro do site referente ao número que digitou, porém não estou conseguindo concluir esse processo, se poder ajudar

Answer (score -3):

Isso porque voce está pegando o valor do input de forma errada na sua função `ver()`.

```
function ver(){
   location.href="/"+document.calculator.display.value;
}
```

De uma estudada na sintaxe básica do `getElementByID` do javascript que vai entender como selecionar elementos para manipulá-los ou recuperar seu valor.

Primeiro de um `id` ao input que voce quer recuperar o valor (no seu caso o input `display`):

```
<input name="display" id="valor_atual_display" value="" .../>
```

Depois é só pegar seu valor por meio do `getElementByID` como voce estava fazendo, porém usando a sintaxe correta:

```
function ver(){
   location.href="/"+document.getElementById("valor_atual_display").value;
}
```

O mesmo vale para o seletor `forms` do javascript nessa linha:

```
document.forms["calculator"].display.value += ch;
```

Compare a sintaxe com o da documentação oficial e veja onde está o erro. Não vou passar de mão a sintaxe de tudo pra não te atrapalhar nos estudos mas vou deixar os link de referencia (dica: está no titulo "Named form access"):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById